# How to use the range based for loop iterator?

Tags: c++, loops, pointers, auto

I have this code for an insertion sort algorithm and I was wondering whether there is a range based for loop equivalent to the for loop that I'm using.

I'm sort of confused with how the range based loop iterator works as compared to the regular STL container iterators. just plainly substituting `for(auto it:x)` clearly doesn't work.

Mainly, my question is how I may dereference that range based iterator to get the corresponding array value.
this is my insertion sort code:

```cpp
for (auto it = x.begin(); it != x.end();it++)
 {
        auto insertloc = std::upper_bound(x.begin(), it, *it);

        std::rotate(insertloc, it, it + 1);
}
```

This code works just fine but I just want to know if I can replace that for loop with a range based one.

Comment: But you're using `it` to rotate, right? Seems like you'd need to look it up regardless.

Comment: The `for(auto it:x)` is misleading, you don't get an iterator `it` but an actual element of the sequence, so you can not possibly use it in cases where the position of the element in the sequence is needed. That said, it's also not clear whether that code you show works or doesn't work, [edit] your question to clarify that. Also, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Range-based for loops are great when you just need to loop over a collection and use each item in the collection.  If you need the indices or iterators, stick with the standard for loop.

Comment: The range based for loop does not provide an iterator in the body of the loop.   It provides the value (e.g. `for (auto element : container)` or `for (int element : container)` if `container` contains elements of type `int`) or a reference to the affected element of the container (e.g. `for (auto & element : container) {element = 5;}` can be used to assign all elements of the container to `5` (if allowed)).   If you need an iterator in the body of the loop - and your example does - generally it is better to use alternatives other than a range-based loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to replace that for loop with a range based one.

That would not work for your use case. The range-for loop works when you only need the value of the object that you get by dereferencing the iterator. It is not going to work for your case since you are using the iterator in the loop. There is no standard mechanism by which you can get the iterator from the value.